# Excel index match conditional between start and end date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have PartNumbers with Status SE and PRS.

All PN start like PRS, and after dedicated date change status from PRS to SE

[image: Tables with Main data and Table with Monitoring]

I need lookup or index, match or similar to get this Table with monitoring

So in column C (status)  should be take out from main table depended of PN and date in Column A.
For example PN 123 on 07.06.2020 had status PRS, but all date after that date should have status SE.

I tried with INDEX, MATCH but i don't get nothing smart

Please help me!
I can even change tables if is necessary, Any suggestion is good !
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a Date column in the Main table?

Comment: Hi @Rmatkov, logically you are supposed to get only one value that is, SE,, coz has similar PN & DATE in both Tables, for PRS the PN 123 is common but hasn't DATE in Main Table,,, plz [edit] your post to avoid confusion !!

Comment: Your requirement is not very clearly. But maybe you're looking for **SUMPRODCUT** function, please read this function article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e

Answer (score 0):

Going by your 'Main Table' dataset, the column `STARTDATE_SE` seems to have a date only where `Status = 'SE'`.

> This implies if a matching date is not found for the given PN, then the status is 'PRS'

I've created 2 Excel Tables,

1. One for the Main Table, named 'MainTbl'
2. One for the Monitoring Table, named 'MonitoringTbl'

*You can create a table by selecting a range and pressing the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (if your range has a header, check the 'My Table has headers' checkbox)*

*You can rename the table by selecting a cell inside the table > Under the 'Table Tools' ribbon > 'Design' tab > 'Properties' section > Table Name*

The below formula would go into the `Status` column of your Monitoring table

```
=IFNA(INDEX(MainTbl[Status],MATCH(1,(MainTbl[PN]=[@PN])*(MainTbl[STARTDATE_SE]=[@Date]),0)),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@PN],MainTbl[PN],0)),"PRS",NA()))
```

[image: index-match-conditional-result]

I hope this helps.